# Run process in background in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way in Android development to have a process run in the background of the app, even if the app is not active.  For example, if the user starts a process, and then hits the 'Home' button, I want the process to continue running in the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a tutorial about Services. Helped me a lot. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes Android license with Service component to perform a number of tasks in the background.